# Baseline alignment of buttons in SwiftUI on macOS

Tags: macos, swiftui, appkit

I’m trying to vertically align a `Text` and a regular `Button` along their baselines in SwiftUI on macOS. I basically want to replicate this layout from the WiFi preference pane:

[image: macOS WiFi Preference Pane - Alignment Layout]

I expected that putting the said controls into an `HStack` with the alignment set to `.firstTextBaseline` would produce this layout. While this is the case for many other controls, it doesn’t seem to work with non-plain buttons. See the following example:

```swift
HStack(alignment: .firstTextBaseline) {
    Text("Text")
    
    Text("Large Text")
        .font(.title)
    
    Button {} label: {
        Text("Button")
    }
    
    Button {} label: {
        Text("Borderless")
    }
    .buttonStyle(.borderless)
    
    Button {} label: {
        Text("Plain")
    }
    .buttonStyle(.plain)
    
    Toggle("Toggle", isOn: .constant(true))
    
    Picker("Picker", selection: .constant(0)) {
        Text("One").tag(0)
        Text("Two").tag(1)
        Text("Three").tag(2)
    }
    .pickerStyle(.radioGroup)
}
.padding()
```

[image: HStack Baseline Alignment]

Am I holding it wrong? Is there a way to levere the baselines just like in AppKit, or do I have to position the button manually?

Comment: I see the same issue with a Mac target, though interestingly a Mac-optimized Catalyst app works fine. I’d recommend filing this as a bug with Apple.

Comment: @Adam: Done https://github.com/structuredpath/AppleBugReports/tree/main/FB10034253

Comment: This issue seems to be solved on macOS 13 Ventura. Tested with the first beta.